# How SOA based Signal Processing?

Tags: audio, fft, soa, audio-processing, ifft

I am working on a problem regarding noise removal from recorded signals using some Adaptive Filtering ( e.g Wiener Filter ).

It's a typical DSP problem in a following way.

```
  Recording Time Signals
  Windowing into Blocks
  FFT Performing
  Noise Removal Technique (Wiener )
  IFFT
  Results On WaterfallSpectrum
```

### My Problem

Somehow, I need to make it Client/Server based application, or i want it to be developed as SOA based app. I researched over it , but I don't find any possible way or similar applications on audio processing or sound processing  that based on SOA.

Can any body suggest the idea, how can I implement it? and to me it would be advatageous. 
What modules do I need to put as client side and others on server side? ( e.g FFT and Noise Removal Techniques )

### Edit:

Actually, I am having research to perform noise removal from audio or recorded signals.
For that, I have to develop not only straight forward solution, but to make the software component so much flexible and network oriented ( some how client/server oriented ) in a way some operations must be performed at one side and some on other side depending on it's nature ( e.g a lot of amount of data processing on server side ).

All I know How can I record signals from Microphone , and apply FFT on those signals and then finally to filter out noise from those frequencies. I have FFT based library ( KissFFT or AForge.NET ). So , I know what I am doing and what I have to do.
But I don't know how it can be done what I stated above? ( How can I manipulate client/server architecture  based implementation of this problem which part on client side and which parts on server side)?

Regards
Usman

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried?

Comment: I have clearly specified about what I want to achieve.
I am working on noise removal based problem.

For that I am taking signals from outside and passing it to various modules to filter out noise from those frequencies. Finally I would have noise less frequencies to which I would transform back to that state which I would show as signal to some display.
Now I want to achieve this using SOA or Client/Server based architecture.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for advice about what software or products to use to achieve the goal of creating an audio denoising web service and it sounds like you haven't tried anything yet. That's specifically listed under things not to ask about here: http://stackoverflow.com/about because you are a) looking for recomendations and b) haven't tried anything yet (or at least haven't shown your work)

Comment: Bjorn Roche : Thanks for your comments .
as it might go long for explanation, Please have a look on to edit of my original post.